# Creating a website that accesses local java code

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to create a browser based application that can access Java Objects that I have created as part of another project:

For example, say I have created a Book Class that contains the parameter author and isbn:

```
public class Book
{
    public String author;
    public int isbn;
}
```

and I would like to be able to access say Book.author from an html page.

Would greatly appreciate a link to a tutorial on this type of code integration.

Comment: Can't be done unless your code is on the server.

Comment: You already tagged this with `jsp` ... is there something specific you don't understand?

Comment: I was told that JSP was the way to go on this, however I cant find a good tutorials that exemplifies this type of information flow

Comment: JSP = Java *server* pages. As tjameson says, this is a server thing. Can't really be done on the client.

Comment: I am only trying to run this locally at the moment

Comment: @user691839 - Use the guide I've provided to setup Tomcat locally.

Comment: Hover the `[jsp]` tag below the question and click `info` link on the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good guide to setting up Tomcat and Eclipse to develop and deploy servelets and Java Server Pages (JSP): http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/eclipse.html

The tutorial includes importing and testing a sample app, which should show you everything you need.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For a local solution, you might use an JApplet (more modern version of Applet). Search for tutorials for JApplet. JSP is a server side thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an absolute beginner in JSP, take a look at this quick tutorial to get a first impression on the technology:
http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/simple-programs-in-jsp/